# How to avoid assigning acolours for the categorical variable in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I have dataframe with 2 categorical variables ('Model' and 'Origin') and built a bar chart via ggplot. In order to have white spaces inside negative bars (for negative values), I assign every colour to a categorical variable manually: `my_color=c(...)`. However, sometimes a number of categorical variables are lots (e.g. countries) and it's impossible to assign every colour by hand. My question is how to avoid assigning all colours for the 'Model' cat. variable

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame (Origin = c("Canada", "Canada","Canada", "Canada","Canada", "Canada","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA"),
                  Model = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","A","G","C","D","E","J"),
                  poschange = c(60, 45,34,56, 65, 44,40, 55, 35, 24,34,12),
                  negchange = c(-5,-2,-0.5,-2,-1,-0.05,-1,-3,-0.1,-3,-1.5,-0.9))

df2 <- df %>% pivot_longer(., cols=c('poschange','negchange'),
                           names_to = 'value_category') %>% 
  mutate(Groups = paste(Origin, Model),
         value_category = factor(value_category, levels = c("negchange", "poschange")),
         )

my_color = c("A" = '#7fc97f', "B" = '#beaed4', "C" = '#fdc086', 
             "D" = '#ffff99', "E" = '#386cb0', "F" = '#f0027f', "white" = "white","G"="black","J"="blue")

ggplot(df2, aes(value, tidytext::reorder_within(Model, value, Origin), 
                fill = ifelse(value_category == "negchange", "white", Model), 
                color = Model)) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = my_color, breaks = df2$Model) +
  scale_color_manual(values = my_color, breaks = df2$Model) +
  tidytext::scale_y_reordered() +
  labs(fill = "Model") +
  facet_grid(Origin ~ ., switch = "y", scales = "free_y") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
        strip.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.text.y.left = element_text(angle = 0),
        panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to assign colors manually then IMHO the only option is to use one of the existing (or a customized) color palettes. In my code below I use the brewer palette which served as the basis for your manual color palette. To make this work with your code and to achieve your desired result you could first add names to the color palette and add your white category as a an additional color:

```r
library(tidyverse)

my_color <- scales::brewer_pal(type = "qual")(n_distinct(df2$Model))
names(my_color) <- sort(unique(df2$Model))
my_color <- c(my_color, white = "white")

ggplot(df2, aes(value, tidytext::reorder_within(Model, value, Origin),
  fill = ifelse(value_category == "negchange", "white", Model),
  color = Model
)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = my_color, breaks = unique(df2$Model)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = my_color, breaks = unique(df2$Model)) +
  tidytext::scale_y_reordered() +
  labs(fill = "Model") +
  facet_grid(Origin ~ ., switch = "y", scales = "free_y") +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
    strip.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
    strip.placement = "outside",
    strip.text.y.left = element_text(angle = 0),
    panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines")
  )
```

[image]

**EDIT** To switch or set the order of the dodging you could use the `group` aesthetic to explicitly set the order. Additionally, while switching to another color palette shouldn't be a big deal, I added an example code how you could use `colorRampPalette` to interpolate the set of brewer colors if you need more than eight colors:

```r
library(tidyverse)

ncols <- n_distinct(df2$Model)
if (ncols > 8) {
  my_color <- colorRampPalette(scales::brewer_pal(type = "qual")(8))(ncols)
} else {
  my_color <- scales::brewer_pal(type = "qual")(ncols)  
}

names(my_color) <- sort(unique(df2$Model))
my_color <- c(my_color, white = "white")

ggplot(df2, aes(value, tidytext::reorder_within(Model, value, Origin),
  fill = ifelse(value_category == "negchange", "white", Model),
  color = Model,
  group = value > 0
)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = my_color, breaks = unique(df2$Model)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = my_color, breaks = unique(df2$Model)) +
  tidytext::scale_y_reordered() +
  labs(fill = "Model") +
  facet_grid(Origin ~ ., switch = "y", scales = "free_y") +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
    strip.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
    strip.placement = "outside",
    strip.text.y.left = element_text(angle = 0),
    panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines")
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Warning in RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n, pal) :
  n too large, allowed maximum for palette Accent is 8
Returning the palette you asked for with that many colors

Comment: Well, most color palettes have only a limited number of colors. One option would be to use `scales::hue_pal` (the default ggplot2 palette) or `scales::viridis_pal()` which allow for any number of colors. Another option would be to use e.g. `colorRampPalette` which allows to create a palette with any number of colors using interpolation.

Comment: One more question, how can I start ordering with positive bars? Like: pos, neg,pos,neg.... because in this case ggplot start with negative bars from the top

Comment: You could set the order of the dodging via the `group` aes. See my edit.